# Trying to transfer an auto hot script to Autokey but getting not defined

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, autokey

First I had a stroke so I learned to type from the middle of the keyboard with one hand. I use `alt + k` for example to hit return. Anyways this script I use for Windows **Auto Hot Key**.

```
!f::Send, {Tab}// alt + f = tab
!k::Send, {Enter}// alt + k = enter
!i::Send, {Backspace}// alt + i = backspace
!y::Send, {Up}// alt + y = up arrow
!h::Send, {Down}// alt + h = down arrow
!g::Send, {Left}// alt + g = left arrow
!j::Send, {Right}// alt + j = right arrow
!,::Send, {=} // alt + , = =
!.::Send {U+0060} // alt + . = `
!/::Send, {-}// alt + / = -
^,::Send, {[}// ctrl + , = [
^.::Send, {{}// ctrl + . = {
^/::Send, {(}// ctrl + / = (
^m::Send, {:}// ctrl + m = :
^n::Send, {$}// ctrl + n = $
```

I'm trying to do the same thing for Ubuntu **Autokey**.
From the documentation, I tried a few different things.

```
 keyboard.send_key(enter, repeat=1)// NameError: name 'enter' is not defined
 keyboard.send_key(return, repeat=1)// NameError: name 'return' is not defined
 keyboard.send_key("enter", repeat=1)// nothing no error but does not hit enter.
```

Is there a key list I should be using because I can't seem to find it.
Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? I'm currently learning javascript from TOP so not trying to learn python atm. But I think I can pull it off with an example or two.

Comment: Probably these are the key names for the Python: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer, I guess you need the <> with "" marks for it to work. `keyboard.send_key("<enter>", repeat=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

These are the key names for the Python: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys

Your third attempt, `keyboard.send_key("enter", repeat=1)`, is correct syntax. The reason it does not result in visible effects is because your system sees that <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> is pressed. Sending an "enter" causes applications to see <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Thus, first having the software "release"  <kbd>Alt</kbd> may give the desired effect: `keyboard.release('alt')`.

I probably would use `xdotool` rather than autokey for this function. A command such as

```
xdotool  keyup alt sleep 0.1 key Return
```

can easily be bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> through your desktop's keyboard shortcut function, "Settings" - "Keyboard"  in the default Ubuntu desktop. The small pause between releasing the Alt and sending Enter appears necessary, so if you stick with Autokey, you may also need to introduce a small delay.

Note that for any of these approaches, you need to be running X11. Recent versions of Ubuntu default to Wayland, but from the login screen, you can change to Xorg. For now, the availability of keyboard automation tools on Wayland is very limited.